# changing float->numeric casts from assignment to implicit, dangerous?

Tags: postgresql, best-practices, datatypes, cast

In porting an application to PostgreSQL (9.1), one odd SQL incompatibility I've discovered concerns the `round()` function, specifically the version that takes a second argument indicating the rounding precision.

In MySQL, `round(some_float_column, 2)` works as expected, returning the value of `some_float_column` rounded to two decimal places.  In Postgres it errors with `ERROR:  function round(double precision, integer) does not exist` and suggests `HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`.

As indicated by the docs...
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-math.html
...Postgres has two round functions, `round(value)` which takes a double precision *or* a numeric, and `round(value, precision)` which takes a numeric *only* and an integer.

So, I don't understand why the two-argument form of round doesn't take a double to begin with, but whatever.  In searching I discovered two solutions to this problem.  One is to simply create my own version of `round(value, precision)` that takes (double, int) and wraps the existing (numeric, int) version with an explicit cast.  That certainly works, but I don't like it (my background is in Oracle which doesn't even have a true floating point type).  It seems to me that float/double ought to be implicitly castable to numeric.  And it turns out that an ASSIGNMENT cast for these types comes pre-defined.  But ASSIGNMENT doesn't work for function calls, as we see here, it would need to be IMPLICIT.  The trouble with *that* is that only one cast can be defined per pair of types, and the float4->numeric and float8->numeric assignment casts are required by the system and can't be dropped.  So the only way to make those casts implicit is to `update pg_cast set castcontext = 'i' where castsource in (700,701) and casttarget = 1700`.

Now we're into hacking the catalog, and that's a sign that this *might* be a bad idea.  But I don't have any hard evidence that it's bad.  Float/double values are inexact, and numeric values are exact, so it seems to me that casting from the former to the latter would be fully data-preserving and therefore logically safe.  The only potential problem I know of would be introducing ambiguity into other functions' argument patterns, but the purpose of asking this question is mainly to fish for potential problems I *don't* know of.

So, is it dangerous to change the float->numeric casting behavior from ASSIGNMENT to IMPLICIT?

Comment: None of these answers even try to answer the question: Why won't Postgres implicitly cast double precision to numeric type for function matching. According to 10.3.4 of the manual "Function Type Resolution - Look for the best match" http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/typeconv-func.html it seems like it should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, hacking into the catalog is bad.  Reason #1 is that if you upgrade to new version and forget to move the hack, things start breaking. Just running pg_dump and loading to the same version on another instance will also lose the hack.  There's also always the chance that a new version of Postgres will change so much that your hack is now not possible and force you to go back and re-engineer.

Overriding with your own function is the correct way to go.

Answer (score 6):

Please be aware that different rounding algorithms are used for different data types.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-TABLE

> When rounding values, the numeric type rounds ties away from zero,
>   while (on most machines) the real and double precision types round
>   ties to the nearest even number. For example:

```
SELECT x,
  round(x::numeric) AS num_round,
  round(x::double precision) AS dbl_round
FROM generate_series(-3.5, 3.5, 1) as x;
  x   | num_round | dbl_round
------+-----------+-----------
 -3.5 |        -4 |        -4
 -2.5 |        -3 |        -2
 -1.5 |        -2 |        -2
 -0.5 |        -1 |        -0
  0.5 |         1 |         0
  1.5 |         2 |         2
  2.5 |         3 |         2
  3.5 |         4 |         4
```

Comment: Tricky little detail, easy to miss.

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution would be to cast your value:

```
SELECT round(some_float_column::numeric, 2);
```

The result is of data type [`numeric`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html) of course. Cast again, if you need to:

```
SELECT round(some_float_column::numeric, 2)::float8;
```

If you must, create a wrapper function like you describe. PostgreSQL supports [function overloading](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/xfunc-overload.html). 
**Never** hack the catalog for this - see @Matthew's answer for rationale.

Comment: Casting to numeric before rounding may not produce consistent results when combined with `round( float_number ).

Comment: @Results should be consistent, but there is the corner case difference to casting floating point types you demonstrate in your answer.