# Dynamically deciding which operator to use based on the type of the value at hand

Tags: postgresql, query

I'm currently implementing a translation between a proprietary expression language and postgres queries at work. So far a lot of stuff fell in place quite nicely, but now I have trouble with one function.
The source language contains a function (`contains`) that checks whether the first argument contains the second. That means for

- strings: It checks whether the second arg is a substring of the first arg.
- arrays: The second arg is an element of the array (first arg)
- objects/maps/dicts: The second argument is a key of the object (first arg)

Now comes the issue: The translation doesn't know anything about the DB schema, so the queries need to be generic enough to work on different kinds of schemas. So I don't know whether a given field is of a specific type. It is okay to fail in some cases, but I would at least like the code to work for the types text/varchar , text[] and jsonb. But I'm struggling to get even the first two to work.
Here is the (incomplete) WHERE clause of a query that is generated by the translator:

```
CASE
    WHEN pg_typeof(entity.field1)::text = ANY('{text,character varying}') THEN ( entity.field1 LIKE '%' || entity.field2|| '%' )
    WHEN pg_typeof(entity.field1)::text = 'text[]' THEN ( entity.field2=ANY(entity.field1))
    [...]
    ELSE false
END
```

Let's assume (for now) that entity.field2 is a text column. entity.field1 is

- a) a text column
- b) a text[] column

The query works fine for a), as expected. But it fails for b) with:

```
operator does not exist: text[] ~~ text
```

So I broke the query down to:

```
CASE
    WHEN false THEN ( entity.field1 LIKE '%' || entity.field2 || '%' )
    ELSE false
END
```

For a) false is returned, as expected. For b) the error is still thrown. So it seems like the operator type check is run, even if there is no way to reach the code in the `THEN` clause.

I tried to find the reason for that in the docs but I didn't. [This paragraph](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-EXPRESS-EVAL) contains some info on early evaluation, but not related to operator type checks.

So, is there a way to get this to work by catching errors, casting (have tried naively casting to text, that works for `text[]` but not for `jsonb`), or anything else?

Thanks in advance for your help, it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Couldn't you write the function in pl/pgsql?  See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html

Comment: I had hoped that I could avoid that, because I am using an ORM wrapper (typeorm) and use their query builder to build the translated queries. But maybe I will end up using pl/pgsql. I just thought it might be possible right there in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Perhaps I don't get something - what data type is `entity.field1` ?

Comment: @jakubiszon that's the issue. I don't know that at the time of writing this translator library. It could be any type, but for now let's just say it could be `text`, `text[]` or `jsonb`. That library should work without knowing the schema. That's why I'm trying to perform type-dependent logic by checking what type the value has using `pg_typeof`.

Comment: As far as I understand it, you either need to detect the type of data before casting or you need to "try cast". I would recoomend reducing the scope of the question. Take a look at https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/203934/postgresql-alternative-to-sql-server-s-try-cast-function

Comment: I didn't want to try to break the scope down too much, because I didn't want to narrow down the solution space too much. I might have missed another approach, completely different from the one I am trying to take in the example.
Thank you very much for the link to the other question. Something like that could help indeed. I will have a look and try stuff out.

Comment: Is the ORM wrapper incapable of using a stored procedure (eg. called contains) in its queries?  If not, check out how to use function overloading, which could solve your problem.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille thanks I started implementing something similar. I'll post it in an answer. The ORM wrapper also provides a raw connection where I can send the CREATE FUNCTION queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some helpful comments here and from my colleagues at work I ended up creating functions (with overloading) to solve the issue:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION contains(haystack jsonb, needle text) RETURNS boolean AS $$
    DECLARE
      result boolean;
    BEGIN
      CASE jsonb_typeof(haystack)
        WHEN 'array', 'object' THEN
          result := haystack ? needle;
        ELSE
          result := haystack LIKE '%' || needle || '%';
      END CASE;
      RETURN result;
    END;
  $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION contains(haystack text, needle text) RETURNS boolean AS $$
  BEGIN
    RETURN haystack LIKE '%' || needle || '%';
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION contains(haystack text[], needle text) RETURNS boolean AS $$
  BEGIN
    RETURN needle = ANY(haystack);
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then I can just include `contains(entity.field1, entity.field2)` in my query and it works for all three types I need right now. I can also easily extend it to work for more types.

Thanks for all your help