# Help understanding behavior of try_cast() with numeric strings

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, postgresql-11, cast

Erwin made a great, generic [`try_cast` function for postgres](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/203986/234694) (copied below). I'm interested in using it for an EAV schema where attributes are stored with a type field. I can use a similar function (that returns a bool) as a trigger that tests if a value string can be cast to the corresponding datatype to add some type-safety.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION try_cast(_in text, INOUT _out ANYELEMENT) AS
$func$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format('SELECT %L::%s', $1, pg_typeof(_out))
   INTO  _out;
EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN
   -- do nothing: _out already carries default
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When testing it though (in PG11), I found that it fails if casting a decimal number string to an integer type (smallint, int, and bigint) - `try_cast('50.0', NULL::int)`. I'm guessing this is because postgres can't intermediately cast a string to a numeric/decimal type before casting to an integer (which makes sense). `try_cast('50.0', NULL::numeric)` does work, so I might just call that good enough.

However, I played with this line:

```
EXECUTE format('SELECT %L::%s', $1, pg_typeof(_out))
```

And changed the `%L` to `%s`:

```
EXECUTE format('SELECT %s::%s', $1, pg_typeof(_out))
```

And `try_cast('50.0', NULL::<integer-type>)` works without issue. The downside is that other types, like `macaddr/cidr`, fail to cast when they worked before

```
try_cast('192.168'::text, NULL::cidr) -- returns null
-- but 'SELECT '192.168'::cidr' works
```

I'm really curious as to why the `%s` fixes the numeric-type casting and breaks others, and if there's any way to improve the function to satisfy this edge-case. If not, I can live with `numeric`, but I'm worried for others using this function in the future without understanding its limitations.

Thanks for any help or ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `%s` omits the quotes. You can see this by trying `format()` interactively:

```
testdb=# select format('%s', '50.0') as "%s", format('%L', '50.0') as "%L";
  %s  |   %L   
------+--------
 50.0 | '50.0'
(1 row)
```

I don't think there's any way of doing this within try_cast(); as I see it, it's doing the right thing. The string `'50.0'` is legitimately not a representation of an integer, so casting to numeric first is correct.

Comment: Oh, ok! After reading this, I tried `SELECT 192.168::cidr` and got "Cannot cast type numeric to cidr", so that pretty much clears it up. That's sad, but a very crucial detail! I'll go ahead and mark this as the answer (now to figure out how to make a good warning label).