# How to make ON CONFLICT work for compound foreign key columns?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key, exception

I'm having trouble with `ON CONFLICT` not working for foreign key columns where the foreign key is compound.   Here's an example.

```
create table foreign_table (
   id_a text    not null,
   id_b text    not null,
   id   integer primary key,
   constraint ft_a_b_key unique (id_a, id_b)
);

create table my_table (
   id          integer,
   ftable_id_a text,
   ftable_id_b text,
   constraint my_table_a_b_fk
      foreign key (ftable_id_a, ftable_id_b) references foreign_table (id_a, id_b)
);
```

Using this query:

```
insert into tcell_test.my_table (id, ftable_id_a, ftable_id_b) 
    values (3, 'a3', 'b3') on conflict do nothing ;
```

where, say, `'a3'` isn't in `foreign_table`, I would expect the `ON CONFLICT` to handle the error.

Instead I get the error:

> ```
> [23503] ERROR: insert or update on table "my_table" 
>    violates foreign key constraint "my_table_a_b_fk" 
> Detail: Key (ftable_id_a, ftable_id_b)=(a3, b3) 
>    is not present in table "foreign_table".
> ```

Is there a way to correct this so `ON CONFLICT` handles the error?

Comment: AFAIK, what you describe is not a conflict. The construction is a way to handle UNIQUE constraint violations, not constraint violations in general.

Comment: If I understand correctly that you want to insert the given row only if the FK constraint is satisfied and not raise an exception otherwise, then I suggest to change the title accordingly. Something like: *"How to skip INSERT rows silently when FK constraint is violated?"* And please remember to always disclose your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you may be misunderstanding what a `CONFLICT` is.  A `CONFLICT` is a violation of uniqueness, basically the row that is being added should not be added because another row with the same values already exists.

In your example of `insert into tcell_test.my_table (id, ftable_id_a, ftable_id_b) values (3, 'a3', 'b3') on conflict do nothing;`, the `ON CONFLICT` condition will never be reached because you have no primary key or unique constraint on `my_table`:

```
edb=# alter table my_table add primary key (ftable_id_a,ftable_id_b);
ALTER TABLE
edb=# insert into my_table (id, ftable_id_a, ftable_id_b) 
    values (3, 'a3', 'b3') on conflict do nothing ;
INSERT 0 1
edb=# insert into my_table (id, ftable_id_a, ftable_id_b) 
    values (3, 'a3', 'b3') on conflict do nothing ;
INSERT 0 0
edb=# select * from my_table ;
 id | ftable_id_a | ftable_id_b 
----+-------------+-------------
  3 | a3          | b3
(1 row)
```

As you can see in the example above, my second insertion into `my_table` did nothing because there would have been a primary key violation.  If I omit the `ON CONFLICT` clause, I get:

```
edb=# insert into my_table (id, ftable_id_a, ftable_id_b) 
    values (3, 'a3', 'b3');
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "my_table_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (ftable_id_a, ftable_id_b)=(a3, b3) already exists.
```

The message that you mentioned in you original post (`ERROR: insert or update on table "my_table" violates foreign key constraint "my_table_a_b_fk"`) pertains to a Foreign Key violation (not a primary key/uniqueness violation).  This violation occurs when there **should** be a row in `foreign_table` with `id_a=a3` and `id_b=b3`, but there isn't.  The database expects this row to exist because you have defined that `my_table` references `foreign_table` (in other words, `my_table` depends on `foreign_table`).  Because the row doesn't exist in `foreign_table`, your insertion into `my_table` fails.  First, insert into `foreign_table`, and then you can insert into `my_table`:

```
edb=# insert into my_table (id, ftable_id_a, ftable_id_b) 
    values (3, 'a3', 'b3') on conflict do nothing ;
ERROR:  insert or update on table "my_table" violates foreign key constraint "my_table_a_b_fk"
DETAIL:  Key (ftable_id_a, ftable_id_b)=(a3, b3) is not present in table "foreign_table".
edb=# insert into foreign_table values ('a3','b3',1);
INSERT 0 1
edb=# select * from foreign_table ;
 id_a | id_b | id 
------+------+----
 a3   | b3   |  1
(1 row)
edb=# insert into my_table (id, ftable_id_a, ftable_id_b) 
    values (3, 'a3', 'b3') on conflict do nothing ;
INSERT 0 1
edb=# select * from my_table ;
 id | ftable_id_a | ftable_id_b 
----+-------------+-------------
  3 | a3          | b3
(1 row)
```

Comment: is there any similar functionality to ```on conflict do nothing``` for a foreign key violation?

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly you want to insert the given row only if the FK constraint is satisfied - and do **nothing otherwise, in particular do not raise an exception**.

This is **no "UPSERT"**, i.e. not a use case for `INSERT .. ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`, which only works for violations of unique indexes or exclusion constraints. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT)

> The optional `ON CONFLICT` clause specifies an alternative action to raising a unique violation or exclusion constraint violation error.

#### Solution

Use an `INSERT` with a conditional `SELECT` instead. And possibly add a locking clause.

```
INSERT INTO my_table (id, ftable_id_a, ftable_id_b)
SELECT i.*
FROM  (VALUES (3, 'a2', 'b3')) i(id, ftable_id_a, ftable_id_b) -- provide values once
                                                               -- works for multiple rows
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM foreign_table f                                 -- SELECT list can be empty
   WHERE (f.id_a, f.id_b) = (i.ftable_id_a, i.ftable_id_b) 
   FOR    SHARE                                                -- weakest lock
   );
```

The **locking** clause `FOR SHARE` is the weakest lock and good enough for the use case. [Details in the manual.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-ROWS) Without locking, there is a tiny time frame for a race condition between looking the row(s) in the `EXISTS` subquery and the actual `INSERT`: concurrent transactions might `UPDATE` / `DELETE` the FK columns of the row in `foreign_table` in the meantime, which would result in an exception after all - the thing we want to avoid.

If there cannot be such concurrent writes, you can skip the locking.

Be aware of a subtle difference in **type handling** introduced with the subquery. With basic data types `integer` and `text` and appropriate numeric / string literal input, everything just keeps working. But you may have to **cast** input values explicitly for other input/target type combinations that cannot be resolved automatically. See:

- [How to avoid implicit type casts in PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/194975/how-to-avoid-implicit-type-casts-in-postgresql/194983#194983)
- [Casting NULL type when updating multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12427434/939860)

Related:

- [How to use RETURNING with ON CONFLICT in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42217872/939860)