# PostgreSQL ignores index, runs seq scan

Tags: postgresql, index, postgresql-performance, datatypes

My table contains an index for column `total_balance`:

```
\d balances_snapshots
                                          Table "public.balances_snapshots"
    Column     |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |                    Default
---------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+------------------------------------------------
 user_id       | integer                     |           |          |
 asset_id      | text                        |           |          |
 timestamp     | timestamp without time zone |           |          | now()
 total_balance | numeric                     |           | not null |
 id            | integer                     |           | not null | nextval('balances_snapshots_id_seq'::regclass)
Indexes:
    "balances_snapshots_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "balances_snapshots_asset_id_idx" btree (asset_id)
    "balances_snapshots_timestamp_idx" btree ("timestamp")
    "balances_snapshots_user_id_idx" btree (user_id)
    "balances_total_balance_idx" btree (total_balance)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "balances_snapshots_asset_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (asset_id) REFERENCES assets(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
    "balances_snapshots_user_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

And simple query goes for seq scan

```
explain analyze SELECT EXISTS (
  SELECT
    1
  FROM
    balances_snapshots
  WHERE
    total_balance = double precision 'NaN'
  LIMIT 1
) as exists;
                                                                QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Result  (cost=4.75..4.76 rows=1 width=1) (actual time=237365.680..237365.681 rows=1 loops=1)
   InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
     ->  Seq Scan on balances_snapshots  (cost=0.00..9257326.32 rows=1948181 width=0) (actual time=237365.675..237365.676 rows=0 loops=1)
           Filter: ((total_balance)::double precision = 'NaN'::double precision)
           Rows Removed by Filter: 389636289
 Planning Time: 23.985 ms
 Execution Time: 237365.719 ms
(7 rows)
```

How can I make PostgreSQL use index? Or in other words, is there more efficient way to scan table on presence of NaN values?

Comment: Please remember to always disclose the version of Postgres in question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Precise explanation

Postgres has an operator for `float8 = float8` as well as for `numeric = numeric`. But not for `numeric = float8`. One operand has to be cast.

`double precision`, a.k.a. `float8` is the "preferred" data type among numeric types. See [pg_type.typispreferred](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-type.html).

[Operator type resolution](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/typeconv-oper.html#id-1.5.9.7.4) is eventually decided in paragraph *3.d.*

> Run through all candidates and keep those that accept preferred types

`float8 = float8` wins. Your index is built on the operator class for `numeric` and is not applicable. Bang.

#### Solution

Replace that cast to `double precision` in your query with a more sensible cast to `numeric`, matching the type of `total_balance` - like [Stanislav already suggested](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/305633/3684).

Or simply use an untyped literal `'NaN'` without explicit cast. That resolves to the type of `total_balance` in the assignment automatically. See:

- [How to avoid implicit type casts in PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/194975/how-to-avoid-implicit-type-casts-in-postgresql/194983#194983)

#### Optimized solution

> is there more efficient way to scan table on presence of NaN values?

If that's the focus of your queries, a [**partial index**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html) will be ***much*** more efficient for your case:

```
CREATE INDEX balances_total_balance_nan_idx ON balances_snapshots ((true))
WHERE total_balance = 'NaN';
```

The actual index expression hardly matters. I used a constant. See:

- [Postgres partial index on IS NULL not working](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/229924/postgres-partial-index-on-is-null-not-working/230087#230087)

Your `EXPLAIN` output reports close to 400 million rows (`389636289`) and none of them actually have `total_balance = 'NaN'` (`rows=0`). The suggested partial index has minimal size of **8 kB instead of ~ 10 GB (?) for a full index** , hardly any write cost, and makes the query work near instantaneously.

(Do you even need all the other existing indexes?)

The expression in the `WHERE` clause has to match the expression used in queries. **If** there is a good reason for the odd type-mismatch in your query (?) make that:

```
...
WHERE total_balance = float8 'NaN'
```

#### Aside: wasted storage

Speaking of which, reordering your table columns like this will save quite a few MB of storage and RAM:

```
                                          Table "public.balances_snapshots"
    Column     |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |                    Default
---------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+------------------------------------------------
 id            | integer                     |           | not null | nextval('balances_snapshots_id_seq'::regclass)
 user_id       | integer                     |           |          |
 total_balance | numeric                     |           | not null |
 asset_id      | text                        |           |          |
 timestamp     | timestamp without time zone |           |          | now()
```

See:

- [Calculating and saving space in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7431468/939860)

Comment: I read the article about "Calculating and saving space in PostgreSQL" and one thing puzzles me! If you have a column as follows: x NUMERIC (10, 5) and insert 7.12345, you obtain a column size of 9 (see fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=b10044f8d2c8db2a9c8239009329bbbe)). Now, my understanding is that in the above example, the `asset_id` field would align on the next 8 byte boundary which would be 4 + 4 + 9 + 7 - 24th byte wasting 7 bytes?

Comment: Would it not be better to have INT, INT, TIMESTAMP (8 bytes) and start either `total_balance` or `asset_id` (both variable length) on byte 16? If the `total_balance` NUMERIC field had been constructed so that it would never have any more than 8 bytes, even more space could be saved? Same for `asset_id` - CHECK (LENGTH(asset_id) <= 7)? Or can this be taken too far?

Comment: @Vérace: It's an aside, so I didn't go into details. The main point is that the next tuple starts at a multiple of 8 bytes anyway, so we don't lose anything by placing `timestamptz` at the end. We just trade padding within a tuple for padding between tuples. If you want to go into more details, consider a new question.

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that PG has to cast original numeric to double precision:

```
Filter: ((total_balance)::double precision = ...
```

So the index that was built contains numeric, but you need double precision - hence the index can't be used. You need to stay away from casting the values in the column:

```
  WHERE
    total_balance = 'NaN'::numeric
```

PS: it's weird to see NaN in a database. Why not store null?

Comment: database serves a legacy javascript application which is expected to insert NaNs in case of logic failures. Database shouldn't fail on such attempt to not crash this legacy app.

Answer (score 0):

As Stanislav said, the problem is that query filters by first casting total_balance to double precision.

After I created an index on casted value query started using this index:

```
create index balances_total_balance_nan_idx on balances_snapshots (cast(total_balance as double precision));
```

Comment: Maybe you should upvote @Stanislav's post?

Comment: This solution seems sub-optimal.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter unless the query using the weird cast is in a piece of software that cannot be changed, and only the database can be changed. Though your partial index solution would be even better (unless there are other uses for that index than just searching for NaNs).